# in mongodb clusters, is status PRIMARY a signal that it's safe to shut down a secondary?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have 3 servers, A, B, and C.

A is the primary.

I want to scale it up live in production.  I issue the following:

```
mongo A
rs.stepDown()
```

I then do

```
rs.status()
```

and see that B is now in status PRIMARY, does this mean that all of the unsynched writes to A have now passed over to B, and A is safe to shut down and scale up?

If not this, then what? Is there any 100% determinant that it's safe to shut down a former PRIMARY?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a replica set, A, B, and C are supposed to be the same and interchangeable.

Therefore if you step down a primary and another has taken over as PRIMARY, the set as a whole should be consistent and can accept writes (*with caveat*).

Having said that, the recommended method to scale vertically is to perform the scaling on all the secondaries first, and the primary last.

*Caveat*: if a new PRIMARY was elected, all three nodes should contain the same data *if all writes to the set are using majority write concern*. There is a slight chance of acknowledged writes being rolled back, if the write was acked by the primary, and you step it down in the small window of time the write hasn't propagated to any secondary yet. See [Rollbacks During Replica Set Failover](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/index.html) for a detailed explanation on this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Does "elected" mean "you will see is as PRIMARY" in rs.status() ?   Or does elected mean "the cluster has made up it's mind on who will be the next primary, once we finish housekeeping"?  My specific question is, if I see with my own eyes "PRIMARY" in B, does that mean I am 100% safe to shut down A? ("safe" meaning "certain no data will be lost')?

Comment: "Elected" means that a PRIMARY exists in `rs.status()`. In terms of 100% safe to shut down, as mentioned in my answer, it depends on your write concern. If all you're using is "majority" write concern, then it's 100% safe. If you're using the default (w:1), then it's not 100% safe since rollbacks is always a possibility. I strongly recommend you always use "majority".

Comment: Having said that, the possibility of a rollback occurring is relatively small, and it will depend on many bad factors appearing together, e.g. network delays, network partition, hardware doing work at their limit, etc. If your replset can comfortably handle your typical workload, the risk is actually quite small.

Comment: thanks for your help, this was a really high value conversation.

Answer (score 1):

The primary is the first point of contact for any client communication, in this case the write operation. A factor to consider is the *write concern* - it is an acknowledgement mechanism that developers can add to the write operations, and higher levels of acknowledgement guarantees a stronger durability guarantee. See [Write Concern for Replica Sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/index.html).

When the write concern is `1` (this is the default), the client is acknowledged after the data is written to primary A. At this point if the primary is stepped down, and the replication hasn't happened yet to the secondaries (and the secondaries do not have the write), when the A is up again as a secondary it will rollback that particular write which has not replicated to the secondaries.

When the write concern is "majority", the client is acknowledged after the data is written to primary A *and* replicated to one of the secondaries B or C ( note that the majority of a 3 member replica-set is 2). In this case, if the primary A is stepped down, the write data is guranteed to be on one of the members B or C (in addition to A).

A is stepped down, an election takes place, and one of B or C gets elected as new primary. The member which has the most recent data gets preference and this will have the replicated write. Note that the priority of the secondary members also affects which member gets preference to get elected as primary (the default priority is 1, and higher priority members have higher preference). The method to determine which secondary gets to run for an election begins with priority, and whichever secondary node has the latest copy of data. In this case (with write concern "majority"), having a default priority of 1 on all members is beneficial.

Comment: thanks prasad, just to be precision, if rs.status() returns "SECONDARY" for A, and write concern is set to majority, is that a 100% guarantee that A is safe to shut down?  So in a script, I could say 1) stepDown A, 2) wait for A to be in secondary status, 3) resize A and be guaranteed that all writes to A are complete and propagated?

Comment: Running rs.stepDown() on the primary A - once, confirmed by rs.status() returns "Secondary" on member A, I think it is safe to shut down. WriteConcern  Majority makes sure the writes are acknowledged after they are replicated on a secondary  (B or C, please see the last two paragraphs of my answer for more details).